# Couchbase - what is asynchronously index?

Tags: indexing, couchbase

I'm reading up on Couchbase on [this site](https://blog.couchbase.com/create-right-index-get-right-performance/) and came across. I understand indexes at a high level, but that's about it. The second line is just as unintelligible.

`The primary index, like every other index in Couchbase, is maintained asynchronously. You set the recency of the data by setting the consistency level for your query`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that when a document is stored in Couchbase, it is put into a queue to be indexed. The write operation does not wait for indexing to finish. Imagine a situation where your application:

1. Writes some document A like `{'type': 'invoice', 'foo':'bar', ... etc ... }`
2. *Immediately* executes a N1QL query `SELECT * FROM mybucket WHERE type = 'invoice'`

An overly simplistic explanation: Document A will be queued up for indexing after step 1. In Step 2, the N1QL is NotBounded (the SDKs/Server will be NotBounded by default), and *may* not return document A, because it hasn't been indexed *yet*. If your situation calls for it, you can specify RequestPlus (or AtPlus) instead of NotBounded. This will make your query wait for the indexing to finish before executing the query.

An example in C# of using RequestPlus:

```
var request = QueryRequest.Create("SELECT * FROM mybucket WHERE type = 'invoice'");
request.ScanConsistency(ScanConsistency.RequestPlus);
```

This does have performance implications though! RequestPlus will be the worst performance, NonBounded will be the best, AtPlus will be somewhere in the middle.

Note that if you use key/value access instead of N1QL, then you don't have to worry about this. You will always be able to access a document by its key directly, regardless of indexing.

For more information:

- [Request specification (docs)](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/n1ql/n1ql-rest-api/index.html#request-specification)
- [Blog post about AtPlus](https://blog.couchbase.com/new-to-couchbase-4-5-atplus/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and the links. I appreciate it